# Unable to spawn a shell using gdb

Tags: c++, c, bash, gdb

I have this C function in a huge code:

```
void test() {
    char *arg[] = {"/bin/sh", 0};
    execve("/bin/sh", arg, 0);
}
```

I am trying to debug this code using gdb

```
(gdb) call test()
process 1948 is executing new program: /bin/dash
warning: Selected architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386
Architecture of file not recognized.
An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(test) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

Hence the shell is not spawning. How to go about it?

Comment: Which version of gdb are you using?

Comment: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

Comment: Does it launch the shell ok if run without gdb?

Comment: yes! It runs properly when called outside gdb

Comment: This is relevant, http://cygwin.com/ml/gdb-patches/2012-11/msg00247.html

Comment: Yeah, I can replicate this exactly by trying to exec a 32bit binary from a 64bit executable. From @Hasturkun's link, it looks like that's the solution.

Comment: AFAICT, GDB 7.5.1 probably has this fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gdb isn't allowing you to exec a binary with a different architecture, even though it's compatible on your platform. The same occurs if you try to exec a 32bit executable from a 64bit one. This occurs on the latest version (7.5.1) of gdb as well.

If you can compile your code as 32bit without it causing other problems, it would be a workaround.

As per Hasturkun's comment, there is a patch available [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/gdb-patches/2012-11/msg00247.html).